# How to setup Jackson to use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" date format

Tags: micronaut

How can I configure Jackson using micronaut to output dates as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` date format? I tried something like this:

```
@JacksonFeatures(
        enabledSerializationFeatures = {},
        disabledSerializationFeatures = {SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS},
        enabledDeserializationFeatures = {}
)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `jackson.date-format` in `application.yml`